# Статик методы и не статик, Java и Unity

Tags: java, android, c#, unity3d

Вызываю из Unity через плагин Java код, который запускает вибрацию.

Код в Unity

```
public void VibroOn()
{
    AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new 
    AndroidJavaClass("com.freebacon.poosh.UnityVibroManager");
    pluginClass.CallStatic("Vibratethis");
    txt.text = " vibroo";
}
```

Java код в плагине, до которого всё доходит.

```
public static void Vibratethis()
{
    Activity currentActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    Vibrator am = (Vibrator)currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    am.vibrate(2000L);
}
```

Пока всё статик - всё отлично работает. Но стоит мне сделать так

Unity

```
public void VibroOn()
{
    AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new 
    AndroidJavaClass("com.freebacon.poosh.UnityVibroManager");
    pluginClass.Call("Vibratethis");
    txt.text = " vibroo";
}
```

Java

```
    public  void Vibratethis()
{
    Activity currentActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    Vibrator am = (Vibrator)currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    am.vibrate(2000L)
}
```

(убрал static  в методе и вызове метода)

Теперь это не работает! Т.е. когда я вызываю в Unity

```
 pluginClass.CallStatic("Vibratethis");
```

Он активирует статичный метод в Java.

```
 public  static void Vibratethis()
```

А когда вызываю

```
pluginClass.Call("Vibratethis");
```

Он не вызывает НЕстатичный метод в Java

```
public void Vibratethis()
```

Компиляторы не в Unity, не в Android Studio не выводят ошибок, в чем же дело и как решить?

Comment: Проблему то может опишите? Вы написали только то что делаете, а что не так - нет.

Comment: @zTrap Добавил изменения, спасибо.

Comment: У класса можно вызвать только статичные методы, не статичные принадлежат экземплярам класса (объектам). А вы пытаетесь вызвать не статичный метод у класса.

Comment: ... поэтому вам нужно "раздобыть" экземпляр данного класса `AndroidJavaObject` (например, с помощью статического метода в классе), а уже для него вызывать нестатический метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в java классе статичный метод, который создает и возвращает экземпляр класса (**getObject**).

**Java**

```
public class UnityVibroManager{
    ...
    public void Vibratethis(){
        ...
    }
    ...
    public static UnityVibroManager getObject(){
        return new UnityVibroManager();
    }
    ...
}
```

Затем получайте этот объект в C# коде и вызывайте у него необходимые методы.

**Unity C#**

```
public AndroidJavaObject object = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getObject");
object.Call("Vibratethis");
```

---

*Но я считаю, для функции вибрации подходит static метод, либо синглтон*

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ.
Что должно быть в Java плагине, кодом?
Я правильно понял что это должен быть статик метод, который создает экземпляр еще одного класса, внутри которого описан метод с вибрацией? 
Напишите пожалуйста, как это должно выглядеть полностью, на примере с вибрацией.